# I need to retrieve whole table even if i use where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

for eg

```
Select *
from SHIRTS
Where size = M and color = red
```

is an sql query .What can i do in this statement so that i can use only size parameter.because u dont know about the user whether he uses size as filter or color.

Comment: Does you query have any parameters?

Comment: Use `if` statements to build up your query.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the values of `size` and `color` in variables like `@s` and `@c`, then you can use `coalesce()` to check if they are `NULL` or not:

```
select *
from SHIRTS
where size = coalesce(@s, size) and color = coalesce(@c, color)
```

In case any of the 2 variables is `NULL` then that condition will return `TRUE`, so the other condition in the `WHERE` clause will filter the query.
In case both variables are `NULL` then the `WHERE` clause's condition will be `TRUE` and all the rows of the table will be returned.

Comment: can you please elaborate it....i just need the same thing that you explained...but i am confused how to it...

Comment: I assume that you have the 2 parameters in 2 variables. If any parameter does not have a value, set the variable to null.

Comment: actually the thing is i am working on an e-commerece app. I have created my database in mysql . i have made a table named SHIRTS now the thing is as it is not sure how many filters the user is going to use to retrieve the collection of shirts...so will i have to make all the possible queries for filtering or can i retrieve the filtered collection of shirts using a single query......plz help

Comment: Include in one WHERE clause all the columns that you may use in the filter just like the code: `where column1 = coalesce(@c1, column1) and column2 = coalesce(@c2, column2) and .....`

Comment: SELECT * FROM SHIRTS WHERE SIZE = M AND COLOUR = RED AND GENDER = F;  this is my command can u plz write a proper code for this so that i may use either of them two of them or all of them

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with the code in my answer. This is not the way to filter.

Comment: Thank u bro i now have learnt the use of it but one problem still exist.....if i write city = coalesce(null,city)  it works ....but if i write city = coalesce('$city',city)   it does not work ...$city is having the value null ...

Comment: If $city is null then it should work because this is what coalesce does: it returns the 1st non null value. Maybe instead of null it is a blank string like `''`?

Comment: dont know bro i assigned $city=null  as well as $city=''   but in both case function returns nothing the only thing which is working is if i write directly null in the function.....i am confused why is it happening

Comment: You are referring to php code. My code has Mysql variables. This is a different thing. I can't help you with php and how to set the variables to null. See these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141111/how-to-insert-null-value-from-php-variable-to-mysql-staying-away-from-sql-injec and https://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/insert-select-update-null-value_t

Comment: no problem thnk u so much bro...u just helped me with something i was stucked in..